# Preventing dupliactes in MySql through PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am new to PHP. And I'm trying to prevent duplicates through php script. I use wamp server. here's the code,

```
$query1="select COUNT(email) from customer_info where email=$eml";
$res1=mysqli_query($db_Con,$query1);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res1);
```

I wanted to know if $row here has the count value. i.e If xyz@abc.com already exists(one occurance) in "customer_info", wil $row be having the value "1"??

And what exactly should be passed to mysqli_fetch_assoc() ? I got a warning saying it expects "mysqli_result" , not a boolean.

P.S: I don't want to make the column email in my table as UNIQUE.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you want to put a UNIQUE index on your email column?

Comment: Not using an UNIQUE constraint will lead you to inconsistency if there are concurrent connection.

Comment: I wanted to know the alternate ways, as a beginner I am more interested in exploring PHP functions.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(email) AS res FROM customer_info WHERE email = $eml"; // res is a alias... can be any unreserved word
$st = mysqli_query($db_con, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_object($st); //mysqli_fetch_object bind the resultset as object into the variable as described here http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_object

// $row->res is a object with property "res" from your query
if($row->res > 0)
{
  //has an e-mail
}
else
{
  ///
}
```

Comment: $row->res what's with this?

Comment: "res" is a alias used in you query:

SELECT COUNT(email) AS "res"


$row is a object... i've used the mysqli_fetch_object to bind the resultset as described here

http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_object

Comment: "mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given" used the same code you gave. Do I need to enable anything in config or what? I'm using Wamp server2.2

Comment: this error in mysqli_fetch_object happened because the mysqli_query returned an error. Verify the variable $db_con